# Determine if running on a Raspberry Pi in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm developing a UI which also runs on a Raspberry Pi (currently with Raspbian).

With the os object I can get information about the OS. But how can I be sure that I'm running on Raspbian or in general on a Raspberry Pi?

```
console.log(os.platform()); // 'linux'
console.log(os.release()); //'3.12.28+'
```

Comment: what's the point? what should happen if your UI runs on Beagle or Panda or hundreds of other ARM-based linux-running boards?

Comment: For example that i would expect an GPIO only on as raspberry pi.

Comment: no idea how you would go about it but should you not be checking for GPIO support instead? Raspbian can be run on qemu on any platform for instance.

Comment: Hmm thinking about this your right. Do you have an starting but on whot to detemerine that there is a gpio support?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check for Raspbian read the file /etc/os-release and check for ID=raspbian.

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux jessie/sid"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

To check for a Pi read the file /proc/cpuinfo and check for hardware BCM2708.

```
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2708
Revision    : 0010
Serial      : 00000000f7094d77
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on joan's answer I've created a tiny Node.js [library](https://github.com/fourcube/detect-rpi). It can be used to check if node is currently running on the RPi.

You can install it through:

```bash
npm install detect-rpi --save
```

To use it, you can use the following snippet:

```js
var isPi = require('detect-rpi');

if (isPi()) {
  console.log('Running on Raspberry Pi!');
} else {
  // ...
}
```